# Is there an SVG viewer that gives error messages?

Tags: svg, debian

I'm learning SVG, so I'm making a lot of basic SVG, DOM and ECMAScript errors. They are extremely hard to discover because I haven't found an SVG viewer that will report them. Is there one?

I am working in Debian Squeeze. I've been using Iceweasel (Firefox), Epiphany (Webkit) and Emacs to view my SVG files. Iceweasel and Epiphany fail quietly when they are given incorrect SVG files. SVG ECMAScript errors do not appear in Iceweasel's error console. Emacs is nice to work with because I can toggle between an SVG file's code and image output, but it will not run embedded ECMAScript. I run as much of the ECMAScript as I can in Spidermonkey first to debug it, but of course there isn't much code I can do that with.

Comment: I've been experimenting with the programs suggested below. 

Opera and the W3C Validator are a good combination. Opera's debugger has an error console for ECMAScript, and lets me inspect an SVG drawing's DOM tree after the scripts have run. There's an option in Opera's developer tools menu that can immediately submit a page to the W3C Validator. 

Batik lets me edit elements in an SVG's DOM tree and shows me the results immediately, which is instructive, but complicated ECMAScript-generated drawings make it grind to a halt. (That could be because of my slow computer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Opera](http://opera.com/) outputs a selection of errors in the built-in error console (reachable through the Opera menu, Page > Developer Tools > Error console).

It's also possible to use Opera's Dragonfly debugger (similar to Firefox' Firebug) to catch all sorts of errors in the content (css, javascript, svg etc). It's also reachable via the Opera menu, Page > Developer Tools > Opera Dragonfly or by rightclicking on the content and selecting "Inspect Element".

You can also view source on svg content and then edit the svg, to see the result click the "Apply changes" button (then switch back to the tab showing the svg). Not as advanced as Emacs for editing of course, but still quite handy for minor edits.

Answer (score 1):

[Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) is pretty strict and will throw up error messages more eagerly than browsers.  It's packaged for Debian as [libbatik-java](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libbatik-java).

Comment: I can't seem to be able to tick two "accepted answers", but this does work too.

Answer (score 1):

The [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) will work on SVG files - expand the 'More options' section and you'll see several different versions of SVG listed.  That can help shake out basic syntax errors.

I'm not sure how to get ECMAScript errors within SVG documents, but you might want to investigate the [web console](http://daviddahl.blogspot.com/2010/07/web-developer-console-in-firefox-40.html) in the [Firefox 4.0 nightly](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-trunk/) and see if that's any better than the 3.6 error console.